# MongoDB - Cannot create field 'ChildProperty' in element {ParentProperty: is null}

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-update

I have a User class:

```cs
public class User
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public String? Name { get; set; }
    public Address? Address { get; set; }
}
```

and Address class:

```cs
public class Address
{
    public String? Street { get; set; }
    public String? City { get; set; }
    public String? State { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to implement partial updating. This is done dynamically, but let's say someone sends to update a User's City and State, I do:

```cs
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Id", id);
var updates = new List<UpdateDefinition<BsonDocument>>();
updates.Add(Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("Address.City", "New City Value"));
updates.Add(Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("Address.State", "New State Value"));
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Combine(updates);
var bsonDocument = await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update, new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<BsonDocument>
{
    ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
});
```

This works well, except if a User's Address is `null`. In that case, I get the error:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command findAndModify failed:
> Cannot create field 'City' in element {Address: null}.

Is there any way to ensure the Address object is created so that the City and State properties get set? I would like to do it without getting the current object from the database.

Answer (score 3):

Think that you may work with update with aggregation pipeline to update the `Address` field dynamically.

Work with `$cond` operator to check whether `Address` is `null`.

If yes, set the whole object to `Address`.

If no, merge the current `Address` value with the document.

The query below may looks complex:

```
db.collection.update({
  Id: /* Id */
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      Address: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$Address",
              null
            ]
          },
          then: {
            "City": "New City Value",
            "State": "New State Value"
          },
          else: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$Address",
              {
                "City": "New City Value",
                "State": "New State Value"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

```cs
var addressDocument = new BsonDocument
{
    { "City", "New City Value" },
    { "State", "New State Value" }
};

var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Pipeline(new PipelineStagePipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>
(
    new PipelineStageDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>[]
    {
        new BsonDocument("$set", 
            new BsonDocument("Address", 
                new BsonDocument("$cond", 
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { 
                            "if", 
                            new BsonDocument("$eq", 
                                BsonArray.Create(new object[] { "$Address", null })) 
                        },
                        {
                            "then",
                            addressDocument
                        },
                        {
                            "else",
                            new BsonDocument("$mergeObjects", 
                                BsonArray.Create(new object[] { "$Address", addressDocument }))
                        }
                    }
                )
            )
        )
    }
));
```

Comment: I am also possibly updating properties at the User level like Name.  So, if Name, City, and State come in as updates, how would I include Name in this as well?

Comment: Yes, you can include the Name field in the `$set` stage. Example: https://gist.github.com/yongshun950824/b9d69545e7379b55c859a50e62481a57

Comment: Ok, I'll try to work this into my code where the properties getting updated are dynamic.

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work with my app, but because the properties to be updated are dynamic, I have to utilize a builder.  Unfortunately, I do not see how to utilize builders and combine like I do with Update.

Comment: @ScubaSteve If you want to use builders you can try "var pipeline = EmptyPipelineDefinition<>" and use above mentioned aggregation in it. 
Then you can do  "var update = Builders<>.Update.Pipeline(pipeline);" and finally
"coll.UpdateOne(filter, update);"

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/update-with-aggregation-pipeline-in-c-net/154146/2